# Voice Recognition Speed

Tags: visual-c++, speech-recognition

I have an application that recognize human voices and process commands. I'm using SAPI 5.3 right now but I would like to know how to decrease time to process commands.

The method which run when recognition event fired is :

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE VoiceRecognitionHandler::NotifyCallback(WPARAM, LPARAM)
```

which is part of sapi53.h specification

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE NotifyCallback(
                                 WPARAM wParam,
                                 LPARAM lParam) = 0;
};
```

The default time seems to be about 1.5 seconds or so. But I would like to decrease to .5 or sooner. The default value is predefined and I don't know if that can be changed.

Comment: Tinker with the [response speed properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I have this SPPROP_RESPONSE_SPEED properties. How should I modify that to get the proper response.